# Using Flyway can i migrate after specific version?

Tags: database, flyway

Is there a way to tell flyway to migrate only the sql files after certain versions? For eg I have v1, v2, v3, v4 files. I need to migrate only v3 and v4. Also i should perform this without bringing in the concept of flyway `baseline`.

Comment: That's exactly the purpose of the `baseline`. Why do you have such a restriction ?

Comment: I believe `baseline` can be set just once. My requirement is that i need to omit SQL files at regular interval.